# Java library for boolean minimization

Tags: library, java

I'm looking for a good library in Java that supports minimization of boolean expressions (for example with the [Quine McCluskey algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine%E2%80%93McCluskey_algorithm)).

EDIT (12.2018): the [LogicNG project](https://github.com/logic-ng/LogicNG) has implemented a [QuineMcClusky algorithm](https://github.com/logic-ng/LogicNG/blob/master/src/main/java/org/logicng/transformations/qmc/QuineMcCluskeyAlgorithm.java) now.

Answer (score 1):

#### [Quine_Mccluskey.java](https://github.com/archie94/Quine-McCluskey/blob/master/Quine_Mccluskey.java)

> Code for Quine McCluskey method of minimization of boolean expression.
>
> LANGUAGE USED : JAVA
>
> HOW TO COMPILE AND RUN :
>
> Open the source file using any java IDE (BlueJ , eclipse ,etc) . Compile the code and run . There is primarily one input the number of variables . The number of minterms and the minterms are randomly generated . ( Code tested in BlueJ IDE and eclipse on Windows 8 )

Source [Code for Quine McCluskey method of minimization of boolean expression.](https://github.com/archie94/Quine-McCluskey)